# Correct syntax to unregister a callback in the DiskArbitration framework

Tags: macos, swift3, diskarbitration

I'm going to implement an observer to be notified when a specific volume disappeared.

The notifications in `NSWorkspace` are not an option, because I need a notification about *device switched off* rather than *device unmounted*.

Registering is pretty easy ( I left out the error handling)

```
var callbackSession : DASession?

let callbackSession = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault)
DASessionSetDispatchQueue(callbackSession!, DispatchQueue.global())  
DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback(callbackSession!, nil, volumeDidDisappearCallback, nil)
```

The callback closure is

```
let volumeDidDisappearCallback : DADiskDisappearedCallback = { (disk, context) in
   // do something with disk
}
```

---

The unregister method

```
func DAUnregisterCallback(_ session: DASession, _ callback: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

expects an generic `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` rather than one of the specific callback types.

When I pass the callback closure to the `callback` parameter I get

> Cannot convert value of type 'DADiskDisappearedCallback' (aka '@convention(c) (DADisk, Optional) -> ()') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer'

My question is: How can I convert the callback object `volumeDidDisappearCallback` to `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`?

Comment: Does passing `unsafeBitCast(volumeDidDisappearCallback, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)` to the deregister function work?

Comment: @MartinR It works even without unregistering the callback but I want to release the resources correctly. It compiles if I make the closure mutable and pass `&volumeDidDisappearCallback` but is this valid? Your suggestion compiles, too.

Comment: The callback type is declared as `@convention(c)`, so this is essentially a (C compatible) function pointer. Therefore casting it to a pointer might be the right thing. But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it, too. I'm just porting an ObjC project to Swift and got stuck at this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DADiskDisappearedCallback` is defined as

```
public typealias DADiskDisappearedCallback = @convention(c) (DADisk, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Swift.Void
```

which is the Swift mapping of the C function pointer

```
typedef void (*DADiskAppearedCallback)(DADiskRef disk, void *context);
```

The unregister function is defined in C as

```
void DAUnregisterCallback(DASessionRef session, void *callback, void *context);
```

with a `void *callback` parameter, and in C you can pass the various
kinds of callback function pointers (`DADiskAppearedCallback`, `DADiskDescriptionChangedCallback`, ...) without casting.

In Swift you have to cast the function pointer to a void pointer explicitly:

```
let cb = unsafeBitCast(volumeDidDisappearCallback, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
DAUnregisterCallback(callbackSession!, cb, nil)
```